# Is centripetal acceleration constant?

Tags: acceleration, centripetal-force

In the case of a car traveling around a corner at a constant speed, the velocity, while constant in magnitude, is obviously changing direction and thus a centripetal acceleration directed towards the center of rotation must exist. Is that acceleration constant or does it vary because velocity is changing direction?

Comment: The definition of constant acceleration is the velocity changing at a constant rate. According to F=ma, constant acceleration is produced by a constant force.

Comment: If the direction of a vector is changing, the vector is changing.  What does that tell you? Think precisely.

Comment: if the velocity's magnitude changed constantly (it varies), the centripetal acceleration, by definition, would vary in magnitude, no longer forming a circular path.

Comment: @Obliv : This is not quite right. See the circular motion on the right semi-circle in my answer and especially its velocity and acceleration diagrams. It's an example with detailed position vector $\:\mathbf{r}(t)\:$,
velocity vector   $\:\mathbf{v}(t)\:$ and acceleration $\:\mathbf{a}(t)\:$.

Comment: @frobenius well this was meant to be taken with the assumption that the rate of change of the direction of the velocity was constant and that only the magnitude varied.

Answer (score 1):

The centripetal acceleration will always be directed towards the center of the circular arc that the car's instantaneous path is a part of. Thus, the direction of the acceleration will be along the line joining car's position and the point about which it is in instantaneous circular motion. We can  easily visualize that during a turn, this line is changing and so is the direction of the centripetal acceleration. The magnitude of the centripetal acceleration might or might not be constant throughout the turn - depending on how the roughness of the road changes. But since the direction is changing one can safely say that the centripetal acceleration is changing.

Answer (score 1):

For a car going around a corner of a constant radius moving with a constant speed the **magnitude** of the centripetal acceleration will be constant but the **direction of the acceleration** will change.  So we would have to say that the centripetal acceleration is not constant in the same way that the velocity is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When we talk about kinematics of a point particle, mainly the velocity and acceleration vectors, it would be reasonable to use differential geometry to understand what is going on. The motion of a point particle is described fully if it's given its position vector $\:\mathbf{r}(t)\:$ as function of time $\:t\:$. Then the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{v}(t)\:$ and the acceleration vector $\:\mathbf{a}(t)\:$ are the 1rst  and 2nd derivative  of the position vector $\:\mathbf{r}(t)\:$ with respect to $\:t\:$. Nothing more, nothing less.

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}\left(t\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\left(t\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a}\left(t\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}\left(t\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^{2}\mathbf{r}\left(t\right)}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}  
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

An example is the plane motion of a point particle as in Figure. The particle describes first from left a semi-circle with uniform circular motion, then in the middle a semi-ellipses and finally to the right  a semi-circle with nonuniform circular motion. Its position vector  is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}\left(t\right) =
 \begin{cases}
 \left[-7-3 \cos\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \;3 \sin \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right]   & t \in [ 0,2\pi)  \\
\left[4\cos\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \;3 \sin \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right] & t \in [ 2\pi,4\pi)\\
\left[7-3 \cos \left(\dfrac{t^2-16 \pi^2}{16\pi}\right), \;3 \sin \left(\dfrac{t^2-16 \pi^2}{16\pi}\right) \right]  & t \in [ 4\pi,\sqrt{32}\pi] 
\end{cases}
\tag{03a}
\end{equation}

The velocity vector is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}\left(t\right) =
 \begin{cases}
 \dfrac{3}{2}\left[ \sin\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \; \cos \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right]   & t \in [ 0,2\pi) \\
\dfrac{1}{2}\left[-4 \sin\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \; 3\cos \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right] & t \in [ 2\pi,4\pi) \\
\dfrac{3t}{8\pi}\left[ \sin \left(\dfrac{t^2-16 \pi^2}{16\pi}\right), \; \cos \left(\dfrac{t^2-16 \pi^2}{16\pi}\right) \right] & t \in [ 4\pi,\sqrt{32}\pi] 
\end{cases}
\tag{03b}
\end{equation}

while the acceleration vector is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a}\left(t\right) =
 \begin{cases}
 \dfrac{3}{4}\left[ \cos\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \;- \sin \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right]  & t \in [ 0,2\pi) \\
\dfrac{1}{4}\left[ -4\cos\left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right), \;-3 \sin \left( \dfrac{t}{2} \right) \right] & t \in [ 2\pi,4\pi) \\
\ \dfrac{3}{8\pi}\left[ \sin F\left(t\right) +\dfrac{t^2}{8\pi} \cos F\left(t\right) ,\; \cos F\left(t\right) -\dfrac{t^2}{8\pi} \sin F\left(t\right) \right] & t \in [ 4\pi,\sqrt{32}\pi] 
\end{cases}
\tag{03c}
\end{equation}
where in the 3rd case of above equation (03c) and in order to shorten its length
\begin{equation}
F\left(t\right) \equiv  \dfrac{t^2-16 \pi^2}{16\pi} 
\tag{04}
\end{equation}

The acceleration vector is analyzed in two components :

1. The orbital component $\: \mathbf{a}_{\Vert}\:$  tangent to the curve, that is parallel to the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{v}\:$ and responsible only for the changes of the magnitude this vector.
2. The centripetal component $\: \mathbf{a}_{\perp}\:$  normal to the curve, that is normal to the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{v}\:$ and responsible only for the changes of the direction of  this vector.

In this example and given the velocity and acceleration vector diagrams for each case  :

1. On the left semi-circle the particle executes uniform circular motion. The velocity vector has constant magnitude (speed), the acceleration vector has constant  magnitude and is always normal to the velocity. There is no orbital acceleration component.
2. On the middle semi-ellipses the velocity vector is changing continuously both in direction and magnitude because of the centripetal and orbital components of the acceleration   respectively. The acceleration vector is  changing also continuously both in direction and magnitude.
3. On the right semi-circle the particle executes nonuniform circular motion.  Both vectors are changing continuously both in direction and magnitude.

Note that  in the example the velocity vector is a continuous function of time, while the acceleration vector is discontinuous at points $\:\mathrm{E}\:$  and $\:\mathrm{I}\:$.

---

**EDIT**

The well known equation for the magnitude of the centripetal acceleration 
\begin{equation}
\Vert\mathbf{a}_{\perp}\Vert = \dfrac{\Vert\mathbf{v}\Vert^2}{\rho}= \dfrac{v^2}{\rho}
\tag{05}
\end{equation} 
is valid not only for circular motion but for every curvilinear regular motion where $\:\rho\:$ the  **radius of curvature** . In Figure below see details around point F of Figure above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation of all is to glance at the formula:

$$a_{rad} =\frac{v^2}{r}.$$

$a_{rad}$ is the magnitude of the radial (centripetal) acceleration. So the answer is clearly **yes**, the magnitudes of the radial acceleration is constant because the speed is.

Only direction changes all the time in order to always point towards the centre, as you already pointed out.

If you did *not* keep constant speed, but you kept driving around circular path at the same distance to the centre (so $v$ would change but $r$ would stay constant), *then* $a_{rad}$ would necessarily have to change as well (corresponding to a smaller og larger "pull" towards the centre in order to keep you on track).